# Store a number in an integer string and recall it in a later action

Tags: cocoa-touch

I'm currently trying to get a UISlider to work.

I'm trying to set the strings value as 8 to start off with on view load.

Then when the slider changes value I want the string to update with that number, and then later on I can use the value in the string for a setDuration:## later on in another action.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using CAFloat..

Answer (score 2):

To update the string you just get the value and do:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [slider value]];
```

To get the string value back as a float you just do:

```
float myValue = [myString floatValue];
```